# Logger for both Python and C++

Tags: c++, python, logging

I'm looking for logger which has an API for Python and C++.

I need that because in my project I have a C++ core and a system of scripting in Python. I'd like to use one logger for both of them.

Comment: log4cxx might be good choice. see more discussion on how to use it in python at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995027/managing-logs-warnings-in-python-extensions

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [azouk-libraries](http://code.google.com/p/azouk-libraries/).

It is mentioned in its official page that it is a

> client library that formats and renders log entries on both stderr and
>   binary logging stream suitable for machine parsing for both C++ and
>   Python.For gluing C++ and Python it uses Boost.Python.

Answer (score 0):

try out c-log,https://github.com/0xmalloc/c-log     ,and then make a extension for python

Comment: Please expand your answer and format it better. Links may become invalid at any time and your answer may not be clear then.